# Write ArrayList<object> to file as string

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to write an ArrayList of objects to a text file. I would also like it to only write the first 43 lines. My code so far:

```
                ArrayList<seat> seats1 = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
                        "seats.txt");


                for (int i = 0; i < 43; i++) {
                    writer.write(seats1.get(i).toString()
                            + System.lineSeparator());

                }
                writer.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


        }
```

This writes the first 43 lines of the array but it outputs the object hashcode rather than a string.

Comment: You need to override `toString` in your class to customize the output.

Comment: Did you overwrite `toString()` in your `seat` class?

Comment: @Radiodef what would i put in the method, sorry i'm new to this

Comment: @PM77-1 nope, what would i put in the method, sorry i'm new to this

Comment: You put whatever you want to write in to the file. This answer has examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/2891664